# Why does my handson table duplicate itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I tried implementing the `handsontable` , but my table got duplicated. I don't understand why this happens. It gets duplicated when I use the `$('#example').handsontable` method. Here is my full code

```
<html>   
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jquery.handsontable.full.css">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://handsontable.com/">
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/top.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head> 

<body> 

<div>
<div id="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
<div id="example" class="handsontable"> <table class="htCore" style="display: table;"><colgroup><col style="width: 50px;"><col style="width: 61px;"><col style="width: 50px;"><col style="width: 69px;"><col style="width: 50px;"><col style="width: 69px;"></colgroup><thead><tr><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">A</span></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">B</span></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">C</span></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">D</span></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">E</span></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">F</span></div></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class=""></td><td class="">Maserati</td><td class="">Mazda</td><td class="">Mercedes</td><td class="">Mini</td><td class="">Mitsubishi</td></tr><tr><td class="">2009</td><td class="">0</td><td class="">2941</td><td class="">4303</td><td class="">354</td><td class="">ede</td></tr><tr><td class="">2010</td><td class="">5</td><td class="">2905</td><td class="">2867</td><td class="">412</td><td class="">5284</td></tr><tr><td class="">2011</td><td class="">4</td><td class="">2517</td><td class="">4822</td><td class="">552</td><td class="">6127</td></tr><tr><td class="">2012</td><td class="">2</td><td class="">2422</td><td class="">5399</td><td class="">776</td><td class="">4151</td></tr><tr><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr></tbody></table></div>  

    <script>
      var data = [
        ["", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes", "Mini", "Mitsubishi"],
        ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
        ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
        ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
        ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151]
      ];

      $('#example').handsontable({
        data: data,
        minRows: 1,
        minCols: 6,
        maxCols: 6,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        autoWrapRow: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true
      });

      $('.ver').html($('#example').data('handsontable').version); 


    </script>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I see

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove `table` inside `<div id="example" class="handsontable">`. This code :

```
$('#example').handsontable({
    data: data,
    minRows: 1,
    minCols: 6,
    maxCols: 6,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    autoWrapRow: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
  });
```

create the table using the data provided. Then no need for table definition inside `<div id="example" class="handsontable">`.

Comment: Exactly. Just for reference, you should never define anything inside the div you are using for your HOT instance. The idea is that HOT itself will generate the HTML needed to display the table. If you define it first and then have a script use that same div, it will generate it twice. What's worse is that it'll probably also duplicate the work and do twice as much every time you modify the table.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are appending into the #example container after already having the HTML table in it, thus creating a 2nd table.